# SAGA difference tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, qgis-processing, saga

I am using QGIS 3.4 Madeira. I want to use difference tool from SAGA from the processing tool box since my data has some invalid geometries and want to fix the issue later after using difference tool so that some invalid geometries are reduced. However, I can't find the tool while searching. I could find the tool while using QGIS 2.18 Las Palmas. Does any body have idea how can I find find SAGA difference tool in QGIS 3.4?

Comment: Do you still have 2.18 installed?

Answer (score 3):

I also keep an installation of QGIS 2.18.28, because it was a long term release for so long that there were practically no bugs left. I usually don't use it, in fact I am very satisfied with QGIS 3, but I keep it.

The SAGA Difference algorithm has known issues. Don't ask me what issues, I don't know them. But someone was careful to clarify that it has known issues to avoid its use.

You can show algorithms with known issues, from the *Settings* menu, *Options*, *Processing*.

[image: 1]