How can I detect which geometries degenerate into lines on running QGIS difference tool
I run difference tool between two area layers.
Sadly, it failed with "Could not add feature with geometry type MultiLineString to layer of type MultiPolygon"
It seems that some of geometries are extremely similar and area degenerates into line.
How can I at least detect in which place it happens? Currently my only idea is to manually split dataset into two, run difference on each, check which fails and repeat. Such binary search will find offending location but it will take hours of manual annoying work. And if I have more places like this...

Hmm, or maybe I can configure qgis to skip such degenerate cases?

I often get your error when unioning. I sometimes manage to solve it buy Snap to Grid, a small Buffer or by simplifying the geometries, to change the geometries very slightly

Do the SAGA or Whitebox Difference tools work?

@John Have not tried them yet. I was not aware of them. whitebox one is some proprietary software from https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/geospatial-software/ - right? I have not figured yet at all how to get SAGA running. I see say https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344455/saga-difference-tool-in-qgis but it is ancient

For Whitebox see https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/wbw-qgis-plugin/  For the current way to get SAGA see https://github.com/north-road/qgis-processing-saga-nextgen   Both plugins are reachable via the standard Manage and Install plugins menu option in QGIS.     You need to have SAGA and Whitebox Workflows installed on your computer. I think the Whitebox plugin gets that program for you.  SAGA can be added as part of the OsGeo4W installer, maybe it's included in the typical Windows install.  If you have an older version of QGIS things may be a bit different.

I have Linux (sorry for not mentioning), so typical Windows install is not relevant.
